# Installing PHP in IIS 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, iis, wordpress, windows-xp

I know there have been some similar questions to this, but they haven't helped me.

I'm trying to install Wordpress 2.8.4 on my XP box, with **IIS 5.1**. I installed MySQL, and found that it was possible to install Wordpress through the Microsoft Web Platform Installer. After installing Wordpress (the install worked fine), I proceeded to the next step in the Wordpress installation documentation, which is to open wp-admin/install.php in your browser. IIS seemed to not be interpreting PHP, and when searching for the best way to install it, I saw that it is also available with Microsoft Web Platform Installer, so I installed it that way. However, my IIS isn't interpreting PHP still. I do not know what the problem is, but I'm going to reboot right now and see if that helps, as I didn't reboot after the install (even though it didn't say I have to). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it seems that SO isn't too alive at this hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application mapping for .php extension to x:\php5\php-cgi.exe is needed.

Open properties  dialog box of IIS's Default Website, and perform extension mapping.

Comment: is this in the ISAPI Filters tab? The name of the filter would be ".php" correct? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, i found C:\Program Files\PHP\php5.dll, as far as I remember, there was something i read while searching for a solution to this problem that mentioned such a file name, is this the correct filter? I'm going to try it now.

Comment: No. It is at **Home Directory** tab. Select **Configuration** button and add path of php-cgi.exe at executable and .php as an extension.

Comment: No, still not working. Going to try to find a php-cgi.exe, but where would this directory be located?

Comment: @adatapost oh. going to try that.

Comment: @adatapost Thank you! It worked after a reboot! Have a great day.